# Problem of Non-Terminating Function (no dependencies)

Tags: c, frama-c

Using Frama-C, I am trying to slice just one source code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct
{
 int event;
 int status;
 int* msg;
}pbBLEEvt_t;

int msgq_receive(pbBLEEvt_t *buff);

void PB_Main_event_send(int, int, void*);

static int PB_ble_ps_state = 0;

static void PB_PacketProcess_IDLE_STATE(int *buf) {
    int service_id = buf[0];
    switch (service_id) {
         case 5:
            PB_Main_event_send(0, 0, ((void *)0));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

static void PB_IncomingPacketHandler(int *buf) {
    switch (PB_ble_ps_state) {
        case 3:
            task_sleep(100);
            break;
        case 4:
            PB_PacketProcess_IDLE_STATE(buf);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void PB_ble_control_task(void * arg) {
 int r;
 pbBLEEvt_t BLE_msgRxBuffer;

 for(;;) {
     r = msgq_receive(&BLE_msgRxBuffer);

     switch(BLE_msgRxBuffer.event) {
         case 1 :
             switch(BLE_msgRxBuffer.status) {
                 case 2 :
                     PB_IncomingPacketHandler(BLE_msgRxBuffer.msg);
                     break;
                 default:
                    break;
             }
         default:
            break;
     }
 }
}
```

The slice command is the following:

```
SOURCE="test.c"
MAIN="PB_ble_control_task"
CALLS="PB_Main_event_send"
OUTPUT="framac_output.c"

frama-c -c11 $SOURCE -lib-entry -main $MAIN -slice-calls $CALLS -slicing-level 2 \
-then-on 'Slicing export' -print -ocode $OUTPUT \
2>&1 | tee framac_msg
```

I found the following frama-c message:

```
[from] Non-terminating function PB_PacketProcess_IDLE_STATE (no dependencies)
```

When I change the local variable of "BLE_msgRxBuffer" in the PB_ble_control_task() function into a global variable, I obtained a sliced code that I wanted.

1. What does the message of "no dependencies" mean?
2. Why did I obtain the sliced code that I wanted after changing the local variable of "BLE_msgRxBuffer" in the PB_ble_control_task() function into a global variable?

Comment: Just some observations: within the code shown, `PB_ble_ps_state` is always zero, so `PB_PacketProcess_IDLE_STATE` will never be called and the `*msg` member of the packet will never be freed.

Comment: Your example is good, but it's not ideal: a few changes are required to make sure it is syntactically valid C code. Providing a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) increases the chances of having a reply. This may be useful for future questions. In any case, I made a few changes to the code to ensure it compiles, though it may not be *exactly* what you had in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your program has undefined behavior, which prevents the slicing criterion (`PB_Main_event_send`) from ever being called, therefore the slice trivially becomes an empty one.

To better diagnose this, I recommend using the Frama-C GUI in this case. Simply replace `frama-c` with `frama-c-gui` in your command-line.

Depending on your Frama-C version, you will either start with the `default` project on the GUI, or the `Slicing export` one. If the latter, simply go to menu Project and click `default` -> `Set current` to return to the initial (non-sliced) project.

Then go to to function `PB_PacketProcess_IDLE_STATE`. You should see something similar to this:

[image: Frama-C GUI screenshot showing the slicing criterion function is never called]

This is the result of running Eva (value analysis) in the program, which is one of the prerequisite analyses invoked by the Slicing plug-in. The red part is unreachable code. It happens precisely when trying to access `buf[0]`, because `buf` contains a scalar, non-pointer value, so it cannot be dereferenced. The alarm emitted by Eva just before (`mem_access: \valid_red(buf + 0)`) indicates it.

Therefore, Frama-C assumes that this branch of code is never executed (no defined behaviors allow it to do so), and there are no other calls to `PB_Main_event_send` in the code. The Slicing plug-in rightfully concludes, therefore, that your slicing criterion is trivial, and produces the simplest program which has the equivalent behavior of never calling `PB_Main_event_send`, which is a mostly empty program.

This also explains your message:

```
[from] Non-terminating function PB_PacketProcess_IDLE_STATE (no dependencies)
```

There are no terminating defined behaviors for this function, because execution *always* stops at an undefined behavior. This is a major indicator that something went wrong, and therefore you should not expect your slice to be meaningful.

Fixing the code (by adding some actual memory pointed to by `buf`, e.g. by changing its declaration from `int* msg` to `int msg[10]`) does produce a slice that more closely resembles what one would expect from this program.

---

For a more direct answer to your first question:

The `from` plugin computes dependencies between function inputs and outputs. It is implicitly used by Slicing (just like Eva). Its default message is:

```
These dependencies hold at termination for the executions that terminate:
```

And then is displays the dependencies it computed.

For non-terminating functions, however, there are no such dependencies, so it simply emits "no dependencies" by default.

---

For a more direct answer to your second question:

When `BLE_msgRxBuffer` is a global variable, **and** you enable `-lib-entry`, its value contains not only the `NULL` pointer (as the default initialization of C), but also a "representative location" (see section *6.3. Describing the analysis context* of the [Eva plugin user manual](http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-eva-manual.pdf)) which can be pointed to, despite generating an alarm. Therefore, when you reach the program point mentioned above, Eva will still generate an alarm (due to `NULL`), but at least *one* execution is able to proceed without undefined behavior. Therefore the call to `PB_Main_event_send` is preserved, and the slicing resembles what you expected.

Comment: Part of the issue might lie in the fact that no code is provided for the function `msgq_receive`, which presumably is tasked with filling the `pbBLEEvt_t` struct according to the current event to be processed.